# How to show list of notifications but with one status bar icon

Tags: android, android-layout, notifications, push-notification, android-5.0-lollipop

Is there a way to have `one` status bar icon, but `multiple entries`(with its own notification id i.e unique) in 
the notification pull down? 
I need to generate a few notifications that each trigger a different 
action when clicked on specific notification, but I don't want to fill the status bar with unwanted icons in the process. Being able to create a notification 
without an icon at all would work too.

**Code:**

```
private void sendUpdatedNotif(final String id,final String title){
    //Notification notification;
    // int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
     int smallIcon = R.drawable.button_close;
     long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
     int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
             ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);   

     Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx, ViewAidActivity.class);

     notificationIntent.putExtra("new_message", title);

     notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

     PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, requestID,    
       notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

     NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
     mBuilder.setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle("You have " +NOTIFICATION_ID+ " new messages.")
        .setContentText(title)
        .setWhen(when)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS).setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);

     if(NOTIFICATION_ID>0){
         mBuilder.setNumber(-1);
     }
     notificationManager.notify(++NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

}
```

Images for reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I need to generate a few notifications that each trigger a different action when clicked on specific notification" -- have one `Notification` with multiple actions. "Is there a way to have one status bar icon, but multiple entries(with its own notification id i.e unique) in the notification pull down?" -- not that I am aware of. "Being able to create a notification without an icon at all would work too" -- that is not possible.

Comment: @CommonsWare.. Is there any workaround. We have basic requirement to have different notification trigeered from GCM but need to show single icon on status bar... like we do have in watsapp,hike,gmail,bluetooth other app icon example

Comment: "but need to show single icon on status bar" -- then you have only one `Notification`. You are welcome to update that `Notification` to reflect newer events, and you are welcome to attach an expanded view (e.g., Gmail at least used to use `InboxStyle`) that will appear when your `Notification` is on top or by a user's two-finger swipe gesture.

Comment: thanks for reply.. we are ok with updating current notification but will it be kind of appeding id (unique) coming from GCM to existing notificant object. and if i clik on that notificatn..will i get list of ids ?? if possible pls provide code snippet

Comment: "will it be kind of appeding id (unique) coming from GCM to existing notificant object" -- well, not really. You are welcome to put whatever you want as extras on the `Intent` inside the `PendingIntent` inside the actions and such, including a list of IDs.